# GUI is not functioning after creating the exe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, user-interface, exe

I have developed GUI in python which has 5 following buttons

- Upload excel button,
- Check inputs button,
- Run button,
- Reset button,
- See the output button

this is how the GUI works:

- After clicking the upload button, we need to load excel button, ( From the excel file data frame will be created using pandas)
- Check input button, will check the heading of the excel file (once the heading matches with predefined headings) then
- Run button will run the program on its back and will give the output
- See output button will go to the next page of the GUI where we can see the output

But after creating the `.exe` using `autopytoexe`, opening it

only the, **Upload excel button** and **reset button** are working and all other buttons and its functions are not working.

I have attached warnings from the `autopytoexe`

```
590792 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement greenlet from package gevent.
590799 INFO: Packages required by gevent:
['cffi']
729965 WARNING: Hidden import "PyQt5.sip" not found!
786987 WARNING: Hidden import "MySQLdb" not found!
787001 WARNING: Hidden import "psycopg2" not found!
794722 WARNING: Hidden import "sqlalchemy.sql.functions.func" not found!

809639 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_lp64.dll
810002 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
810018 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90rtl.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
810028 WARNING: lib not found: pgc14.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
810409 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.dll
810734 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_ilp64.dll
810989 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_ilp64.dll
811415 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.dll
812124 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of c:\programdata\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_lp64.dll

818132 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\irjaed\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxo5yg_wy\build\exe_reset_ver0\warn-exe_reset_ver0.txt
819393 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\irjaed\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxo5yg_wy\build\exe_reset_ver0\xref-exe_reset_ver0.html
820046 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
831543 INFO: checking PYZ
831563 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
831575 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\irjaed\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxo5yg_wy\build\exe_reset_ver0\PYZ-00.pyz
844769 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\irjaed\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxo5yg_wy\build\exe_reset_ver0\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
845067 INFO: checking PKG
845084 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
845097 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
1144547 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
1145215 INFO: Bootloader c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
1145231 INFO: checking EXE
1145257 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
1145269 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
1145291 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\irjaed\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxo5yg_wy\application\exe_reset_ver0.exe
1145936 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: I always use [PyInstaller](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/). I never had such a problem. Since I have never used autopytoexe I can't help you except recommending pyinstaller.

Comment: i kind of found that what is the error?.....

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exe_reset_ver0.py", line 75, in headcheck
    messageVar = messagebox.showinfo('Headings info','Column heading ' + head_written[j] + ' is matching with '+ head_actual[j])
NameError: name 'messagebox' is not defined



can you please tell me why it is happening. The above one is the problem , intially i have tried with tk.messagebox.showinfo but it is working fine but it is creating problem in the exe

Comment: Maybe there went something wrong when creating the exe. Have you tried doing it again?